# snap access denied on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, haskell-snap-framework

how to make non-root user  use snap command  direct ?
how to make non-root user  use snap command  direct ?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

```
$ sudo snap list
Name    Version   Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
core18  20200427  1754   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
lxd     4.1       15067  latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd   2.44.3    7264   latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
```

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/99-snapd.conf
# Allow snap-provided applications to work with sudo

Defaults    secure_path += /snap/bin
```

```
$ snap install ruby --classic
error: access denied (try with sudo)
```

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: The file `/etc/sudoers.d/99-snapd.conf` is a mistake: 1) Files containing `.` in filename are not included by `sudo`. 2) It also seems that `secure_path` cannot be modified? --- See https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1882215 --- Solution could be to modify the secure_path in `/etc/sudoers` directly.

Comment: you should  config  the `snap`  environment  in `.bashrc` or others

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the steps**

step1:sudo apt update

setp2:sudo apt install ruby

step3:sudo snap install ruby –classic